# How to prevent SQL Injection for URL Parameter changing (DELETE Statement) PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, url-parameters

I have a code like below for DELETE entry by URL Parameter

```
<td><a href="deletecar.php?car_id=<?php echo $row_cars['car_id']; ?>" onclick=" if ( !confirm('Are you sure to DELETE?') ) return false; ">Delete</a></td>
```

And this is URL Parameter output

```
http://localhost/html/deletecar.php?car_id=17
```

But if i change car_id=17 to car_id=23(which is in an other users car list) it is deleting

How i can prevent this

deletecar.php is like below

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

if ((isset($_GET['car_id'])) && ($_GET['car_id'] != "") && (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username']))) {
  $deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM cars WHERE car_id=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_GET['car_id'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

  $deleteGoTo = "myaccount.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $deleteGoTo .= (strpos($deleteGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $deleteGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $deleteGoTo));
}
?>
```

And this is my table in database

```
INSERT INTO `car` (`car_id`, `c_id`, `c_brand`, `c_model`, `c_model_nd`, `c_model_year`, `c_color`, `c_capacity`, `c_owner`, `c_statu`, `c_show`) VALUES
(16, '34DA1593', 'Volkswagen', 'Volt', '313 CDI', 2006, 'Beyaz', '', 18, 'yakamozturizm', 'Boş', 0),
(17, '34BC5897', 'Mercedes', 'Sprinter', '313CDI', 2006, 'Gri', '', 14, 'PcRestorer', 'Boş', 0),
(18, '34DBC145', 'Volkswagen', 'Volt', '213 CDI', 2013, 'Beyaz', '', 16, 'PcRestorer', 'Boş', 0);
```

Edit....

i have changed my code like that

```
$colname_delete = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['car_id'])) {
  $colname_delete = $_GET['car_id'];
}
$owner_delete = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
  $owner_delete = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
}

if ((isset($_GET['car_id'])) && ($_GET['car_id'] != "")) {
  $deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM minibusler  WHERE car_id = %s AND c_owner =%s", 

GetSQLValueString($colname_delete, "int"),
GetSQLValueString($owner_delete, "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

  $deleteGoTo = "myaccount.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $deleteGoTo .= (strpos($deleteGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $deleteGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $deleteGoTo));
}
```

It looks working do you think it is secure way to do that

Thanks For Your HELP

Comment: This is not an SQL injection by any means. The rest of the question is okay and there is nothing to downvote for.

Comment: first condition looks quite useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make it less bloated

```
if (empty($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
  exit; // take appropriate action here
}
if (empty($_GET['car_id'])) {
  exit; // take appropriate action here
}

mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
$sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM minibusler  WHERE car_id = %s AND c_owner =%s", 
                GetSQLValueString($_GET['car_id'], "int"),
                GetSQLValueString($_SESSION['MM_Username'], "text"));
mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error(mysql_error());

header("Location: myaccount.php");
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

In any case before deleting a `car` you should check that if it belongs to the current user. If not display a suitable message.

Comment: Yes im asking what is the best way to do that

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) from cars, users WHERE car.car_id=? AND car.owner=users.user_id` (for some, probably oversimplified, guess at what your database structure looks like)

Comment: Not knowing the structure of you database, I cannot say much. But basically you should make a query and fetch the car's owner id and compare it with the current user's id.